# waiting for sms timed out twilio android

Tags: java, android, twilio

Hey i am using twilio to send messages to my users in my app but it worked for a couple of months now it doesn't but it shows me this error in my logs:

`com.twilio.verification.external.VerificationException: Request failed: -101 [Waiting for sms timed out]`
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

do you know the free project is limited ?
I think you have to create another project

Comment: And how can i make my project not free?
I don't want to create another project.

Comment: I think in dashboard click  on charge now

Comment: I already did it and i have a paid project.
my balance is about 22$ now

Comment: Not a Twilio error / error code. Are you having connectivity issues to the Twilio API? https://api.twilio.com/. Your TLS library up to date? https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007820133-FAQ-Twilio-REST-API-s-TLS-and-Cipher-Suite-Security-Changes-for-June-2019